# VSCode detect current container port automatically from launch.json

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code, debugging

I have successfully configured VSCode to attach the debugger to a node process running within a container using the following configuration:

```json
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "Foo API",
  "remoteRoot": "/opt/nodeservice",
  "port": 52885,
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder:foo-api}",
}
```

However, this currently requires a manual step where I execute a command to determine the current port (52885 in the above example) and paste the value into the `launch.json` because launching the debugger. Mutating the `launch.json` in this way means it cannot be source controlled.

I have various combinations of environment variables, input variables, command variables and prelaunch tasks without success.

**Is there a way to automatically attach to the correct port when launching the debugger in VSCode without modifying the `launch.json` each time the port number changes?**